# What does qPicture::play function do?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Its given on documentation of Qt that "Replays the picture using painter, and returns true if successful; otherwise returns false." But I am not able to understand what does qt mean by replay and play word.

Answer (score 1):

`QPicture` represents a sequence of `QPainter` drawing instructions. "Play" means re-execute those instructions against an instance of `QPainter` (usually different from the one those instructions where originally recorded against).